# net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT error is coming while making a post request in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, post, async-await, request, fetch

While making a post request to sandbox server, I'm getting connection timeout error. i.e.

```
post_request.html?key=somekey&command=verify_payment&var1=20200317131848&hash=675adda10bf0a137d815a16dab357014102dceb3f39ee3b6cfc07261ca57ef4d4fdfcd5577408282e650520f528d97f22ad14f0bb735bf282f4f07aa3da587dc:35 POST https://test.someurl.in/merchant/postservice?form=2 net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

My complete request is this:

```
  <script>
    document.getElementById("formid").onsubmit =(e)=> {
        e.preventDefault();
        const url = "https://test.someurl.in/merchant/postservice?form=2";

        var data = new URLSearchParams();
       // console.log(e.target);

        for (const pair of new FormData(e.target))
        {
            data.append(pair[0],pair[1]);
        }


        console.log(data);
        fetch(url, {
            method:"post",
            mode: "no-cors",
            body: data
            
        }).then(res=> res.json())
        .then(res2=> console.log(res2));

    }

    </script>
```

I've also tried with CORS extension but no luck :(

Please help, thanks in advance :)

Comment: have you tried if the server is up and respond to the request from other client like (postman). if so how long it took?

Comment: Yes, I've tried with postman too, taking same time (around 1 minute), but still the error is same : Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 10.200.12.133:443.   but I'm sure server is up because by hitting on readme (swagger yaml is there), it is giving proper response.

Comment: there is probably a problem in this specific endpoint on the server. the server can be up but if the socket response idle, you get a timeout as the client can't wait indefinitely

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll get it checked but as far as I know the same endpoint is working fine on Swagger. I am wondering if something is wrong with my JavaScript code ; )

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the js code and you confirmed it by requesting directly from postman it doesn't work either? does it ?

Comment: No, it's not working even with postman. Will confirm here after few hours (raising it to network ops team), again thank you for your help.

Comment: I've added CORS extension to browser & then changed some code, Now the response is coming. ```         .then((response) => {
        // *** Check for HTTP failure
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error("HTTP status " + response.status);
        }
        // *** Read the text of the response
        return response.text();
    })
    .then((message) => {
        // *** Use the text
        alert(message);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        /* ...*** handle/report error, since this code doesn't return the promise chain...*/
    });
    }

    </script>